# Conflicting implementations error for two related traits

Tags: rust, traits

I'm trying to implement some accessor traits for a field of type `A`.

Some structs will always have `A`, some other structs may or may not have it depending on their data.

For the first case, I defined `AAccess` trait.

For the second case, I defined `OptionalAAccess` trait.

```rust
struct A;

// Define the base traits
trait AAccess {
  fn get_a(&self) -> A;
}

trait OptionalAAccess {
  fn get_optional_a(&self) -> Option<A>;
}
```

Since `AAccess` always implies `OptionalAAccess`, I added corresponding implementation:

```rust
impl<T> OptionalAAccess for T where T: AAccess {
  fn get_optional_a(&self) -> Option<A> {
    Some(self.get_a())
  }
}
```

Here is where it gets blurry. I also tried to make it work with `Result<T, E>` where both T, E implements `AAccess` or `OptionalAAccess`.

```
impl<T, E> AAccess for Result<T, E>
where
    T: AAccess,
    E: AAccess,
{
    fn get_a(&self) -> A {
        match self {
            Ok(value) => value.get_a(),
            Err(err) => err.get_a(),
        }
    }
}

impl<T, E> OptionalAAccess for Result<T, E>
where
    T: OptionalAAccess,
    E: OptionalAAccess,
{
    fn get_optional_a(&self) -> Option<A> {
        match self {
            Ok(value) => value.get_optional_a(),
            Err(err) => err.get_optional_a(),
        }
    }
}
```

However, it doesn't work due to conflicting implementations:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `OptionalAAccess` for type `Result<_, _>`
  --> src/lib.rs:30:1
   |
11 |   impl<T> OptionalAAccess for T where T: AAccess {
   |   ---------------------------------------------- first implementation here
...
30 | / impl<T, E> OptionalAAccess for Result<T, E>
31 | | where
32 | |     T: OptionalAAccess,
33 | |     E: OptionalAAccess,
   | |_______________________^ conflicting implementation for `Result<_, _>`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0119`.
error: could not compile `playground` (lib) due to 1 previous error
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=dbee8df4870095836f9fb220196c8890)

Is this "diamond" implementation pattern disallowed or discouraged in Rust? Is there some way of doing this?

(This is a toy example for piggybacking certain information to Ok and Err values if it's not obvious already.)

Comment: Maybe this can be made to work with [specialization](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1210-impl-specialization.html) once that is stabilized…

Comment: @Jmb I tried making T implementation default (which should do it in theory IIUC), but it doesn't seem ready yet even with specialization feature enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you were getting close with `Result<T, E>`. You really only need one trait, which returns a `Result`. In cases where the value is not in fact optional, you can make `E` be [`Infallible`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/enum.Infallible.html), which is a type that can never be constructed. (On Nightly Rust, you can use [`!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.never.html) instead, which has better compiler support).

```
trait AAccess {
  type Error;
  fn get_a(&self) -> Result<A, Self::Error>;
}
```

For cases where the `A` is required, set `type Error = Infallible`. For other cases, set it to an actual error type. If there's no better error than "the value doesn't exist, then your error type can be as simple as

```
struct NoSuchAError;
```

Though you might prefer to say

```
#[non_exhaustive]
struct NoSuchAError {};
```

instead if you want to be able to introduce error details later as a non-breaking change.

If you want to write a function that requires *mandatory* `AAccess` (that is, an `AAccess` that cannot fail), you write

```
fn my_function<T>(arg: &T) where T: AAccess<Error = Infallible> {
  ...
}
```

And if you don't care, then simply don't mention `Error` in the constraints.

```
fn my_function<T>(arg: &T) where T: AAccess {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It's slightly inconvenient since `AAccess` cases will be more prevalent in my use case, but a working solution beats a non-working convenient one :)

Comment: @ofo For additional convenience, you can create a supertrait for `AAccess<Error = Infallible>`, which is blanket implemented in terms of the fallible `AAccess`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cc0cae902174b899ffba98257e8d524b

Comment: @FZs That's nicer, but I suspect I might have same issue if I try to implement AAccess and FallibleAAccess for Result<T, E>

Comment: The point of @FZs approach is that you *never* implement the `RequiredAAccess` blanket trait by hand. You have exactly one impl _ever_, and that's the blanket impl coming from `AAccess<Error = Infallible>`. At that point, you're just writing an [extension trait](http://xion.io/post/code/rust-extension-traits.html).

Comment: Oh I see. Makes sense: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fd28428a6f8df2fdba540c47e5611aac

Comment: @SilvioMayolo A follow-up question: Is there a straight forward way for this to work for Result<T, E> where exactly one of T, E is AAccess with Infallible, but not both? The above solution works only if both T, E is fallible or both infallible.

Comment: I think I'm still confused as to why you're trying to get it to work on `Result` at _all_. If `T` is `AAccess` then you can get `Result<T, E>` to `Result<A, E>` with `result_value.map(|x| x.get_a())`. For `Result<T, E>` to `Result<T, A>`, you can do `result_value.map_err(|x| x.get_a())`. You just need to use higher-order functions on the types, rather than trying to put everything under the umbrella of this one trait function. If that's not clear (Stack comments are kind of limiting in how much code I can put here), feel free to ask another question, or we can head to a private chatroom.

Comment: `A` is in reality `codespan::Span`. I'm trying to use this in some custom deserialization library where both Ok and Err variants _may_ (and for some types _do_) return some corresponding span for their context. I tried removing AAccess altogether and using OptionalAAccess only, too, but that ended up with an awful number of unwraps everywhere. I was trying to avoid `blah.map_or_else(|e| e.with_span(span), |v| v.with_span(span))?` as well. I think it doesn't worth the effort without specialization support currently. Thanks.

Comment: @ofo With more trickery you can handle this too, https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3d997bf44874671b63fa8480f760156b.

Comment: @ofo This only allows `Result<AAccess, AAccess>` and `Result<OptionalAAccess, OptionalAAccess>`, not `Result<OptionalAAccess, AAccess>` or `Result<AAccess, OptionalAAccess>`. If you need that, that too can be handled with even more trickery: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5db15523a50eb5f36eca4507d5e5efe1.

Comment: @ofo In general, diamond structure is not supported by Rust (at least today), but there are many other things you can do with Rust's trait system to workaround that.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman This actually does it. Combine pattern is also pretty interesting (and exactly the thing I couldn't figure out above). Thanks.